# Manipulate complex strings using MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

I use mysql database version 8

These are the initial strings

```
M PL20 23 09467
M PL20 23 00517
M PL20 23 00071
M PL20 23 00009
```

I need

- delete the first character in the string from the left (M);
- insert the "-" replacing the space on the string;
- delete all zeros in the string after the character "-"

I have tried this sql query on [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyq9UeXea6vReMTwaMawW3/5)

The return of the sql query it's right

```
PL20-23-9467
PL20-23-517
PL20-23-71
PL20-23-9
```

But do you know a simpler method in MySQL?

Comment: I suggest you read about [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `REGEX_REPLACE` and `CONCAT` and an extra `REPLACE`

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  txt varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO test (txt) VALUES
('M PL20 23 09467'),
('M PL20 23 00517'),
('M PL20 23 00071'),
('M PL20 23 00009');

select 
 concat(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(txt,
       '^([[:alpha:]]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]+)$',
       '$2-$3'),
  '-',
  replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(txt,
            '^([[:alpha:]]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]+)$',
            '$4'),
         '0', '')
  ) as result 
from test;
```

See it working here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyq9UeXea6vReMTwaMawW3/6